# Dumbing down HDMI control on a openelec Pi

Tags: hdmi, openelec

I have home entertainment based around the Pi which works great running openelec gotham, I also have a cable box (foxtel Australia) for watching tv and a harmony remote to connect it all together.

The system is connected to an LG55LM through HDMI.

At First I setup the Pi to be powered from the USB from the TV, But the problem was that if I turn on the tv the pi would start up and force the tv to HDMI-1 (The pi) even if I wanted the cable box. (also I was never to sure if the pi was shutting down correctly)

So to get around this I then plugged the pi's power into the wall, so it was always powered, as it low consumption would not be to much of a problem, but when doing this the tv through hdmi then tells the pi the shutdown when i turn the tv off.

Is there a way to stop any of these HDMI command on the pi to either not send these command from the pi to the TV or for the pi to ignore these command from the tv?

Comment: What you're interested in is **CEC settings.** How those are configured on openELEC I don't know.  Beware apparently not all TVs play nice this way.

Comment: Plug the Pi into a different HDMI port. Often TV's will only have device control on HDMI port 1.